# ViewModel not updating when calling a function update()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have this function:

```
function updatedata(data)
{
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

  if(obj.hasOwnProperty('request_type'))
  {
     if (obj.request_type == 'client_information')
     {

         var ViewModel = function (Clients) {
             var self = this;
             this.Clients = ko.mapping.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(Clients));
         };

         var info = new ViewModel(obj.clients_information);
         ko.applyBindings(info);
     }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="mychats" data-bind="foreach: Clients" data-role="listview"> 
<li class="not_selected" data-bind="id: chatid, text: client_name"></li> 
</ul>
```

The function is called time to time , it can correctly bind the data to the ul when it's called for the first time but not when its being called more than one time.

Comment: If you'd call `updatedata` more than once you might end up calling `ko.applyBindings` more than once, which is bound to give you an error. Have you checked the console? Also, any chance you could slightly rewrite the code in your question so it reproduces your scenario?

Comment: In addition, you should proabably read through [the `mapping` documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), it has some info on how to update view models created with that plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't apply the bindings more than once (which should raise an error - check your console).

Instead of recreating the viewModel each time, just put the clients information in an observable and update the observable with the new client info in the update function.

Something like:

```
 var ViewModel = function (Clients) {
     var self = this;
     this.Clients = ko.observableArray(Clients); // As you use the foreach binding, I assume it's an array
 };

 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

 var info = new ViewModel(obj.clients_information);
 ko.applyBindings(info);

function updatedata(newData)
{
    info.Clients(newData);
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbm1gkht/3/).

Or if you want to use `ko.mapping`:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj);

function updatedata(newData)
{
    ko.mapping.fromJS(newData, viewModel);
}
```

This injects the new data into the existing viewModel.

As an aside, there is no `id` binding. Use `attr: { id: chatid }` instead.